# Events in jQuery UI Datepicker with json data source

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to display events in the jQuery UI Datepicker. I want the days that have events to be styled differently from days that don't have events, and I want to display a custom tooltip with the event details when hovering dates with events.

The solution to the question "[jQuery UI Datepicker with jQuery tipsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300118/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-jquery-tipsy)" gets very close, but doesn't work with the Datepicker configuration I use. I use the "showOtherMonths" option, and it throws the date link calculation off.

The event data is available at http://mydomain.com/events.json

Mockup of what I want:

[image: Datepicker with events]

This is the code I use for creating the Datepicker:

```
$('#dateDiv').datepicker({
    altField: '#dateInput',
    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    firstDay: '1',
    showOtherMonths: 'true',
});
```

I'm not concerned about the CSS part of the solution at this time, just the javascript part. How do I make my custom tooltip appear when hovering the dates with events attached to them? And how do I attach the events (calendar events, not javascript/DOM events ;) )?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very elegant solution, but it does seem to work. Can someone please come up with something better?

**EDIT:** Here's a jsFiddle with the code running: http://jsfiddle.net/Tobbe/JrkSN/3/

**EDIT2:** It works until I click on a date, then all the events disappears because the `beforeShowDay` callback isn't called in that case. How do I work around that?

```
getEvents();

$(function() {
    $('#dateDiv').datepicker({
        altField: '#dateInput',
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        firstDay: '1',
        showOtherMonths: 'true',
        beforeShowDay: beforeShowDay,
        onChangeMonthYear: getEvents
    });
});

var enqueuedDates = [];
var tryCounter = 0;
var events = [];

function getEvents() {
    events = [];
    enqueuedDates = [];
    $.getJSON('events.json', function(json) {
        events = json;
    });
}

function beforeShowDay(date) {
    enqueuedDates.push(new Date(date));

    if (enqueuedDates.length == 35) {
        processEnqueuedDates();
    }

    return [true, '', ''];
}

function processEnqueuedDates() {
    if (!events || events.length === 0) {
        tryCounter++;
        if (tryCounter < 100) {
            setTimeout(processEnqueuedDates, 10);
        } else {
            tryCounter = 0;
        }

        return;
    }

    tryCounter = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < enqueuedDates.length; ++i) {
        var event = getEvent(events, enqueuedDates[i]);

        if (event) {
            var theDateCells = $('#dateDiv .ui-datepicker-calendar td');
            var hideTimeoutID;
            theDateCells.eq(i).addClass('eventPlanned').
                bind('mouseenter', function(eventText) {
                    return function() {
                        if (hideTimeoutID) {
                            clearTimeout(hideTimeoutID);
                            hideTimeoutID = null;
                        }

                        var popup = $('#eventPopup');
                        if (popup.size() == 0) {
                            popup = $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'eventPopup');
                            $('body').append(popup);
                        }

                        var pos = $(this).offset();

                        popup.html('<p>' + eventText + '</p>').
                            css('left', pos.left + 5 + 'px').
                            css('top', (pos.top - popup.height() - 2) + 'px').
                            bind('mouseenter', function() {
                                clearTimeout(hideTimeoutID);
                                hideTimeoutID = null;
                            }).
                            bind('mouseleave', function() {
                                $(this).hide();
                            }).
                            show();
                    }
                }(event.text)).
                bind('mouseleave', function(eventObject) {
                    hideTimeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#eventPopup').hide();
                    }, 200);
                });
        }
    }
}

function getEvent(events, date) {
    return events.filter(function(event, index, arr) {
        return date - $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', event.date) === 0;
    })[0];
}
```

Comment: Did you ever work out how to handle the events disappearing on a click event?

Comment: Found out you just have to manually call your beforeShowDay event (or whatever you use to actually update/show the events) again inside the onSelect event.

Comment: What happens if you have multiple events on the same day, How do you get them all to show?