# Checking Time in Form for User based on admin data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Afternoon All,

I'm finding this time very confusing. Maybe it's because I have no concept of time right now but I have the following in my admin:

```
   t.boolean  "mon",                    default: false
    t.boolean  "tue",                    default: false
    t.boolean  "wed",                    default: false
    t.boolean  "thu",                    default: false
    t.boolean  "fri",                    default: false
    t.time     "start"
    t.time     "end"
```

I have the following form in my bookings:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@booking) do |f| %>
  <% if @booking.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@booking.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this booking from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @booking.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <ul>
  <li><%= f.label :first_name %></li>
   <li><%= f.text_field :first_name %></li>

   <li><%= f.label :last_name %></li>
   <li><%= f.text_field :last_name %></li>

   <li><%= f.label :email %></li>
   <li><%= f.text_field :email %></li>

   <li><%= f.date_select :start_datetime %></li>
   <li><%= f.time_select :start_datetime, :ignore_date => true, :minute_step => 15 %></li>
   <li><%=f.input :length, input_html: { :style=> 'width: 120px'}, collection: [['30 Mins', 30], ['1 Hour', 60]], :class => 'dropdown-toggle' %></li>
</ul>
```

I want to be able for the input on the booking to match the time and days set in the user.

Could anyone help me wrap my head around this time issue. I'm trying to do this in the most pragmatic way but failing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to be able to book a day that an admin is available, and you want to disable those days where they are not. You're going to have trouble with a simple `date_select`. You should use a JavaScript date picker, like the jQuery datepicker plugin. They have a function called beforeShowDay, which lets you pick if a day is available or not:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

```
  $(function () {
    function isAvailable(day) {
      var cssClass = ""; // Becomes the default.
      // currentAdmin will have to be written by you.
      // You'll likely have to pull in information about
      // the admin via some info in the page or, better, 
      // via JSON.
      if (currentAdmin.isAvailableOn(day)) {
         return [true, cssClass];
      } else { 
         return [false, cssClass];
      }
    }

    $("#dp").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: isAvailable
    });
  });
```

Comment: I've never really used Jquery. Could you give me some idea how I'd use the code from the admin table to allow the shown dates and times.

Comment: Here's a longer write up on how to integrate this functionality with your app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178385/rails-how-to-add-tooltip-events-in-datepicker-and-limit-them-in-few-months That said, if you don't have a lot of experience with jQuery or Rails, this might be a bit much to take on for a beginner project.

Comment: I would recommend using a static set of available / non-available days that is hard-coded in your JS file to test with before going with the full JSON route. Maybe code it in Ruby first and then translate to JavaScript?

Comment: My face is bleeding. Would there be another way I can do this without using Jquery as I also need to be able to show times that don't have any events assigned.

Comment: I suppose you can create an entire calendar page as part of the booking creation process.. http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars