# Cluetip doesn't work after changing uidatepicker month

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, uidatepicker, cluetip

Picked **ui datepicker** as calendar and used **cluetip** to show events. Script is working until I change the month (push button <- or ->).
  Main idea was to set title to the element that holds date and on hover show & split text in lines using cluetip.

*EDIT*: Here is [example](http://www.capoeira-latvia.lv/test/calendartest.html) - hope it will help to understand my problem.

Here is the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dates =[ // adding events
[new Date(2010,8,01),new Date(2010,8,03),"Event1 | text | next line"]
];

$('#calendar').datepicker({ 
beforeShowDay: highlightEvents,
});

function highlightEvents(date) {
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
if (dates[i][0] <= date && dates[i][2] >= date) {
return [true, 'odd', dates[i][2]]; } // odd == style 
}

$('td.odd').cluetip({ // cluetip main function
splitTitle: '|',
cluetipClass: 'jtip',
arrows: true, 
dropShadow: true,
});
});
```

Html code:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to UberNeet post:
[jQuery UI Datepicker with jQuery tipsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300118/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-jquery-tipsy)

Found the answer.

```
// Because the the event `onChangeMonthYear` get's called before updating 
// the items, we'll add our code after the elements get rebuilt. We will hook 
// to the `_updateDatepicker` method in the `Datepicker`.
// Saves the original function.
var _updateDatepicker_o = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;
// Replaces the function.
$.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst){ 
   // First we call the original function from the appropiate context.
   _updateDatepicker_o.apply(this, [inst]); 
   // No we can update the Tipsys.
   addTipsys(inst.drawYear, inst.drawMonth+1, inst.id);
};
```

Hope this will help someone.