# jquery ui datepicker with tooltip - tooltip function not call after month change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Im trying to make jquery ui datepicker (inline as calendar) working with tooltip. Everything is working fine, tooltip is showing until I change the month in calendar. Then tooltip stop to work. I dont know how to solve this problem and I will appreciate any help.
Below is my code (I was using [this](http://jsbin.com/enaza/edit) script).

Thanks!

```
$(function() {

var specialDays = {
  '2011': {
    '3': {
      '10': {tooltip: "Some event", className: "holiday"}
    },
    '4': {
      '15': {tooltip: "Some another event", className: "holiday"}
    }
  }
};

$('#datepicker').datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(date) {
  var d = date.getDate(),
    m = date.getMonth()+1,
    y = date.getFullYear();

  if (specialDays[y] && specialDays[y][m] && specialDays[y][m][d]) {
    var s = specialDays[y][m][d];
    return [true, s.className, s.tooltip]; // selectable
  }
  return [false,'']; // non-selectable
}});

/* tooltip*/
$(".ui-datepicker-calendar tbody").tooltip();
```

});

Comment: What tooltip script are you using?

Comment: is a jquery ui tooltip [link]http://view.jqueryui.com/master/demos/tooltip/default.html[/link]

Answer (score 2):

Use this, it's working for me:

```
onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
                            setTimeout("$('.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody').tooltip()", '250');                              
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the functionality of `$('#datepicker').datepicker` inside of a function. Then, pass that function name to the tooltip function as a callback when the tooltip has loaded.

The reason your events are unbinded is because the HTML is changing.

**Further explanation:** At line 115 in the tooltip script there is an event that you can use for callback:

```
var initDatepicker = function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        // Your code...
    }});
};

$('.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody').tooltip({
    // On tooltip open, init the datepicker
    open: initDatepicker
});
```

Comment: Now the calendar is not showing at all. However there is not js errors in firebug.

Comment: OK, probably because `#datepicker` is found earlier in the DOM. Try changing it into a class and the following accordingly: `$('.datepicker').datepicker(...)`

Comment: well, changing it to the class didnt help. I found here similar problem but with diferent tooltip plugin [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300118/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-jquery-tipsy). Unfortunately I still cant figure out how to use it to ui tooltip... Thank you very much for helping.